# Transition to Transparent UINavigationBar (Apple Music like Navigation Bar)

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, transition, transparent, ios9

I'm trying to copy the iOS Music app push/pop transition from a semi transparent to a transparent UINavigationBar, while keeping the UIBarButtonItems visible. Since the navigation bar doesn't move itself, I believe you need to set the UINavigationBar transparent for both UIViewControllers and add a subview to the UIViewController under the transparent UINavigationBar to simulate a semi transparent UINavigationBar. Any solutions for this issue?

[image: iOS Music app transition]

Comment: efremidze, how did you end up accomplishing this?

Comment: I've been using this library: https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition

Comment: I have implemented a configureable framework consistent with your request : https://github.com/yiplee/YPNavigationBarTransition Checkout the example project for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the best github repos I found:

https://github.com/forkingdog/FDFullscreenPopGesture https://github.com/kingiol/KDInteractiveNavigationController https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition

Comment: @avdyushin Thanks, great link!

Comment: @avdyushin It's very cool. But I'm not sure apple will reject apps using that solution or not. Because a private property of UINavigationBar `_backgroundView` is used. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I haven't run into an issue yet. Let me know if you do.

Comment: @avdyushin the link is dead sadly

Answer (score 4):

On your details controller put this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard self.navigationController?.topViewController === self else {return}

    self.transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ [weak self](context) in
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)

        }, completion: { context in
    })
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    guard self.navigationController?.topViewController === self else {return}

    self.transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ [weak self](context) in
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        }, completion: { context in
    })
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, instead of two `setBackgroundImage` function calls one should be the `shadowImage` property in which I set it to a new `UIImage()` instead of nil. Also, the guard statements don’t seem to be needed in mine, not sure if it makes a difference

Comment: Note that for this to work, the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property on your presenting view controller must not include the top edge (i.e. the edge corresponding to the navigation bar). Otherwise, your extended content will show through the navigation bar when it becomes transparent during the transition. If using a table view or collection view, you may need to scroll down before you see this happen. To keep `edgesForExtendedLayout`, you need to create a placeholder navigation bar or try a solution like [TFTransparentNavigationBar](https://github.com/thefuntasty/TFTransparentNavigationBar).